# Recursion string in JAVA

Tags: java, string, recursion

I'm writing with JAVA, and I wrote a recursive boolean function that gets 2 strings and is supposed to return if the first one is prefix of the second one.
My code:

```
public static boolean prefix(String s, String t)
{
    int i = s.length()-1;
    if (s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(i) && s.length() >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I'm writing in the main for example:

```
s = "Del";
f = "Delight";
```

The function is working as well.

But if I'm writing `s = "Dellll"`, `f = "Dell"`, it says "Out of bounds". Why?

The second thing is that it's not working with big and small characters. For example:

```
s ="Dell"
f ="dell"
```

It will return true for the above.

Thank you.

Comment: This does not look recursive? Also you use `s.length()-1` to get the last character of `s` *and* `t` however `t` may be shorter, in which case it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: If you want to check a prefix, why not just use startsWith method?

Answer (score 3):

What about using out-of-box solution?

```
public static boolean prefix(String str, String prefix) {
    return str.startsWith(prefix);
}
```

In case you really need recursion:

```
public static boolean prefix(String str, String prefix) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty())
        return prefix == null || prefix.isEmpty();
    if (prefix == null || prefix.isEmpty())
        return true;
    if (str.charAt(0) != prefix.charAt(0))
        return false;
    // remove first character of each string and go to next iteration
    return prefix(str.substring(1), prefix.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the 2nd code. Its not working as well.

Comment: @liemM which test case is not working for my solution?

Comment: If srt = "sssss", prefix = "f" it will work, one problem solved. But if str = "Dell", prefix = "Dell" -> It will return false

Answer (score 2):

This is because you declare `i` as:

```
int i = s.length()-1;
```

And then call the `ith` char in both `Strings`

```
if (s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(i) && s.length() >= 0)
```

But if the first `String` is bigger than the second then `i` will be out of bounds. An easier way to do this would be to use the built in method [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)), which:

> Tests if this string starts with the specified prefix.

So your method could be as simple as:

```
return t.startsWith(s);
```

Or if you can't use built in methods, then you'll need to check if the first `String` is larger that the second:

```
if (s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(i) && s.length() >= 0 && s.length() < t.length())
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of bounds means that, being the second string shorter than the first one, you are trying to access a character that doesn't exist. Just check the two lengths at the beginning of the function, and switch the parameters internally if needed.